# Issue with data insertion while using TaskExecutor

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my web services application, I implement asynchronous task executor to insert object in database. But at the first time of insertion it throws below exception.

```
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:
```

2nd time when I refresh the url the object is inserted to database successfully.

The problem is with first instance of new request where object is not inserted.

XML file

```
<bean id="applicationEventMulticaster" class="org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster"> 
   <property name="taskExecutor"> 
      <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"></bean>
     </property> 
  </bean>
```

I used `org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` / `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and also child table list are `clear()`, `addall()`. But no luck.

If I comment the task executor tag, all new request objects are inserted properly.
In my scenario, I have to implement asynchronous task executor.

RptServiceImp.java

```
public class RptServiceImp{

@javax.annotation.Resource
private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

@Transactional
 public void process(final RqstLoad rqstLoad ) {

 try {
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new LoggingEvt (this));

  }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("e:: "+e);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

EventListoner.java

```
@Component
public class EventListener implements ApplicationListener<LoggingEvt > {
@Autowired
private EvntRptDAO evntRptDAO ;

 @Override
 public void onApplicationEvent(LoggingEvt evnt) {
  final CustResource custRsrc = event.getCustResource();

   try {
      evntRpt er = new evntRpt (custRsrc);
      evntRptDAO.saveAndFlush(er);
    }
   catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("e:: "+e);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for the Entity and code use use to insert.

Comment: have any idea for the issue

Comment: What is the CustomerResource mentioned in the exception? What is er in the posted EventListener? Looks like you posted just random snippets of your code.

Comment: well what you posted does not make any sense , do you try to insert the same object from different threads at the same time? what are the objects you are referring , and why you need an AsyncExecutor ? you first send a response to the web service , and at the same time commiting to DB? if DB operation throws an exception , how you notify the web service?

Comment: yes. your are telling right. But exceptions are handled in right way. here the issue is task executor.

Comment: The problem is you are using multiple threads, you cannot share hibernate managed objects between different threads. Instead of sending the hibernate managed object send the id and retrieve it on the other end. The issue is things get serialized/deserialized and things get detached from a session (or new instances or created due to deserialization).