# How can i create xml configuration for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with BlockingQueue?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using below xml file. Here i need to inject java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue on ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. How can i do this? share any ideas!

```
<bean id="applicationEventMulticaster"    class="org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster"> 
   <property name="taskExecutor"> 
       <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        </bean>
   </property> 
  </bean>
```

Comment: You cannot, but why would you need that?

Comment: because i getting parallel accessing to save object in database. In my 1st new request object throws org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: exception and also 2nd time send same request object to database it inserted successfully. If i command the task executor, the 1st time of new request inserted successfully. so that, my problem is task executor, at same time, i need asynchronous. if u have idea.. please share it..

Comment: I still don't get your problem. The `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` already uses a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`. So what you are explaining or thinking is wrong isn't the case. Please elaborate more on your use case and what is happening. Post some code and configuration. Why have you configured the  `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` to use a thread pool. Do you really use that or do you want a thread pool for something else. Please improve your question...

Comment: refer this question here i explained ::  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981047/issue-with-data-insertion-while-using-taskexecutor

Comment: The problem is intact the fact that you are sharing hibernate managed objects between multiple threads, that isn't going to work. Hibernate sessions aren't thread safe.

Comment: is there any solution to manage hibernate session with multiple threads? please share code...

Comment: there is no problem in select and update the problem is only to insert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86892/discussion-between-user3091530-and-m-deinum).

Comment: No hibernate sessions aren't thread safe, they cannot and must not be shared amongst threads...